# changing user is ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

In a ubuntu system, I'm logged in to a user named a, and launched two terminals with it.

On one of the terminals, I've logged in to another user named b.

But, when I use the who command, the result says that both of the terminals are owned by 'a'.

I expected :
b@a-virtual-machine:/home$ who
a pts/0 2015-03-15 00:00 (:0)
b pts/3 2015-03-15 00:00 (:0)

but, the result was
b@a-virtual-machine:/home$ who
a pts/0 2015-03-15 00:00 (:0)
a pts/3 2015-03-15 00:00 (:0)

Why is this happening? What am I missing?

Comment: you can try flushing the cache... not sure it would fix it though:  sync; sudo echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_cache

Comment: Also, when logged in to 'b' by 'su - b', the whoami command returns 'b', but the 'who am i' command returns 'a'. What's wrong with me.

Comment: who am i should return a, as its only actually 'who' (disregard the 'am i') and it will show the user you are logged in as. whoami will show the user your effectively logged in as... I do think you could solve this by logging out and initially logging in as b, if that is a possibility